# AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'webdriver'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, chromium

I've installed Selenium correctly as well as the [Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)) webdriver for Selenium, and I keep getting the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Turtle/PycharmProjects/SpotifyWebscraper/seleniumTest.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.chrome()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.chrome()
driver.get("htts://www.google.com")

print(driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)

driver.quit
```

I've checked in the folders correctly and the files seem to be in the right positions:

```
C:\Users\Turtle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\selenium-4.0.0a3-py3.8.egg\selenium\webdriver\chromium
```

contains file *webdriver.py*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the way Selenium imports the various flavours of `webdriver` to `selenium.webdriver` you can see that the import you want is [`Chrome`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-4.0.0-alpha-3/py/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py#L21)

```
from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
from .chrome.webdriver import WebDriver as Chrome  # noqa
```

So you would do `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` or if you want Firefox, `webdriver.Firefox()`

By doing `webdriver.chrome()` you're importing & calling the actual `chrome` [module](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/selenium-4.0.0-alpha-3/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome)

In terms of your new error, you need to download the chromedriver executable and make sure it's in a folder which is available to python (included in your `PATH`). You can download chromedriver here; https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: another commenter noticed this. I have thus fixed the code but now i'm getting a whole different slew of errors: 

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/526891145733603339/671157522954190858/unknown.png

Comment: @ThomasScheer you actually need to download chromedriver. I've added a link to my answer.

Comment: yes, I have already downloaded the chromedriver thank you. I have also created a path to it but the error persists. here is proof:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/526891145733603339/671161841002610716/unknown.png

Comment: @ThomasScheer The python3.8 path which you've got selenium installed to isn't listed in those paths. Perhaps that's your issue. If you need further reading on windows `path` then check this; https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: I just remembered that I updated my python and didn't reset the path. this was the answer. Thanks Mark. this has me a lot of headaches

Comment: One of the best short and sweet explanation I have seen on SO !!!

Answer (score 1):

The error in your title is different than the one in your post.

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

`chrome` should be capitalized in `webdriver.chrome()`:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome() # .Chrome(), not .chrome()
```

Comment: I see. I capitalized the driver and now i'm getting a whole new slew of  error.

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/526891145733603339/671157522954190858/unknown.png

Comment: Looks like you're missing the chromedriver https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: hi Ismael, I am positive that I am not missing the chromedriver. thank you for your input, however.